# Embedding MFC Dialog in MMC SnapIn

Tags: c++, com, mfc, mmc, snap-in

I created a few dialogs in MFC that are spawned from an MMC SnapIn. After review, I was told that it'd be better design to embed the dialogs in the SnapIn (in the Result Pane as a custom view).

The issue is that I have no idea how to do this: I'm guessing I have to create a COM interface that acts as a sink for the COM events that the MMC generates when the user interacts with the MMC, and that I have to translate those events to the Windows Messages that the dialogs expect.

I have no idea if this is even right, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

maybe these pages will help you.

PropPage Sink
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814985(v=vs.85).aspx

WinForms
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692755(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, link #1 is definitely helpful, but it looks like I'm going to create an MFC ActiveX Control project in the solution and link it to the other project (I have a good sample project to go by). Thanks for the answer